# App JAVA WEB com Instalador

Tags: java

Preciso fazer uma aplicação um pouco diferente, já vi algo igual em *PHP*, o famoso *Wordpress* ou *Joomla*, eles funcionam assim:

Você baixa um zip e descompacta no diretório do servidor web (exemplo apache), acessa a URL do contexto (ex: http://localhost/mywordpress), nesse momento a aplicação verifica se existe um diretório com o nome "*install*", se existir ele redireciona o usuário para essa aplicação (*install*), essa por sua vez abre um *wizard* que ajuda o usuário configurar o BD (dentre outras coisas), no final ele renomeia esse diretório "install" e redireciona o usuário para o contexto inicial (aplicação já configurada).

Alguém já fez algo parecido em Java?

Até hoje, minhas aplicações sempre dependem da configuração do BD para subir no `tomcat`, ou seja, se o BD não estiver configurado a aplicação nem sobe, nesse caso imagino que a aplicação não poderia exigir BD no *start*.

Comment: Cara se você souber fazer criação de arquivos já e um passo dado, no meu entendimento uma maneira simples, seria você criar um código que gera um arquivo de texto, com os dados que a pessoa inseriu, apartir desse ponto você pega os dados de conexão por exmplo de dentro desse arquivo. No final  você faz a verificação o se o arquivo com os dados existe, se sim vai direto para o site, se não tela de instalação.

Comment: Exatamente cara... pensei em algo bem parecido, só não sei se seria o melhor caminho, mas acho que vai ter que ser por aí.
Valeu mesmo pela ajuda!